# Android: Why Can't I Override setFrame From View?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, extension-methods, overriding

Simply trying to extend View and do some custom work, but Eclipse will complain when I attempt to override the setFrame method. Claiming there isn't a method in the parent class to override:

> The method setFrame(int, int, int, int) of type Test must override or implement a supertype method

Here is the signature of the method from android SDK source.

```
protected boolean setFrame(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
```

As you can see it's not private or package level, or even specified as final... just protected. Which should mean I am totally able to override it in a subclass. Right? Below is the bare minimum of what I'm trying to do in Eclipse. Perhaps it is just an Eclipse error, but I'm not too familiar with using Ant to check against that.

**Edit: To those answering that setFrame is not defined in the View class, I can assure you it is. How else do you think I got the method signature? It is even called during layout(). Or am I seriously just crazy?**

git HEAD: [View.java](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob_plain;f=core/java/android/view/View.java;hb=HEAD)
Cupcake (1.5r4): [View.java](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/view/View.java;h=0a84aa01d04eaf34c896987fb8bf55fe57438ff5;hb=46e23fe762d2143d60589ab6d39c4b47c2c754d1)

You can even see the method **being overriden** in the [ImageView](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob_plain;f=core/java/android/widget/ImageView.java;hb=HEAD) and [TextView](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob_plain;f=core/java/android/widget/TextView.java;hb=HEAD) classes...this is why I am seriously confused as to why I cannot override it myself from View directly...

```
public class Test extends View {
    public Test(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public Test(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public Test(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean setFrame(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        return super.setFrame(left, top, right, bottom);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation, `setFrame` is not defined in the `View` class (*not strictly true - see edit*). Surprising, each subclass, `TextView` and `ImageView`, define it themselves.  You'll have to have to extend the specific subclass for each widget you want to override this behavior.  This is based on the docs for `Android 2.3 r1 - 05 Jan 2011 12:43`.

See the documentation:

Classes that define setFrame
http://www.google.com/search?q=site:developer.android.com+%22boolean+setFrame%22

[TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setFrame%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) and [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setFrame%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

**Edit:**

As the OP points out in the comments, the method is clearly defined in the `View.java` source code. However, the documentation acts as if the method isn't defined there.

The reason for this is that the setFrame() method in `View` has the @hide Javadoc tag:

```
/**
 * Assign a size and position to this view.
 *
 * This is called from layout.
 *
 * @param left Left position, relative to parent
 * @param top Top position, relative to parent
 * @param right Right position, relative to parent
 * @param bottom Bottom position, relative to parent
 * @return true if the new size and position are different than the
 *         previous ones
 * {@hide}
 */
protected boolean setFrame(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
```

Apparently, this hides the method from the Javadoc:

http://www.androidjavadoc.com/?p=63

> The especial [sic] attention is need to turn to the @hide tag which standard doclet can’t interpret and which ***hides non-SDK source and thus this code shouldn’t be used in applications***.

Is it possible that the reason it can't be overridden is that the Eclipse plug-in for Android or the Android compiler is somehow enforcing the `@hide` tag? I don't know.

Comment: Updated question with links to View.java, ImageView.java, and TextView.java. View defines setFrame, and both TextView and ImageView override it. I am simply trying to do the same... so, what is preventing me?

Comment: @Nicholi - I see what you mean.  I updated my answer to indicate where the info comes from.  The docs don't indicate what your code link shows.  I'm unable to determine the version of your link, but I can only guess that there were recent changes in `git` that are not yet in the SDK.

Comment: I thought it might be recent as well, but you can go all the way back to v1.5 Cupcake and it is the same. http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/view/View.java;h=0a84aa01d04eaf34c896987fb8bf55fe57438ff5;hb=46e23fe762d2143d60589ab6d39c4b47c2c754d1

Comment: Yes I saw the {@hide} tag before, but that is just in relation to doc generation. That shouldn't prevent me from overriding the method, especially when ImageView and TextView can override it just fine. And you are apparently supposed to override them instead of View (MAKES NO SENSE). I fail to see how overriding this method could be so selective :(

Comment: I don't believe even the ADT plugin would be able to enforce that, since the Android SDK comes with no source code. Meaning the tag would have already been removed when the android library was compiled, right? But it seems to be the only thing that almost makes sense.

Comment: @Nicholi - I can't speak as to why they did it, just that they explicitly did hide it. Presumably they had their reasons, e.g. there's some code acrobatics that makes its unsafe to override in some subclasses, so they only expose in the subclasses where its safe.  Regardless, ImageView and TextView is likely the safe approach. if its feasible for you.

Comment: I'm more interested in "how" they did it. A simple tag relating to doc generation doesn't really explain it in my opinion. Unfortunately it's not really feasible to use ImageView/TextView. My aim was to actually extend SeekBar but none of its parents define setFrame themselves, just View. I think I'll just be making my changes in onLayout instead.

Comment: @Nicholi  I agree about the ADT plugin, but its Google - the Javadoc could be used to produce things other than documentation, like a blacklist of hidden functions that the ADT enforces.

Comment: Hmm I suppose you could be right. I'll have to keep on the lookout for more @hide tags. Will wait to see if anyone else has some other ideas before marking you as answer.

Comment: @Nicholi - Well, I'm glad to solve the mystery of why the docs don't match the source code - I learned something today!   And for the record, I've used JavaDoc for non-documentation.  I used a special Javadoc tag to "annotate" (this was before real Java annotations) and servlets and servlet parameters right in the servlet code.  I then used a special Javadoc processor to generate the web.xml template.

Comment: Random update. Been seeing alot of other @hide tags in asdk, some with notes like "pending API council". None of these functions can be called from android lib itself, even though they are clearly there. Seems this tag is definitely used to hide from view certain attributes in the compiled android jar library.

Answer (score 1):

Because setFrame is not defined in the [View class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

Comment: Updated question with links to View.java, ImageView.java, and TextView.java. View defines setFrame, and both TextView and ImageView override it. Care to explain more?